# Missing POM in upload gradle maven flavours

Tags: android, maven-2, android-gradle-plugin, pom.xml

I'm designing an aar Library for Android and am facing an issue.
Since I introduce flavors, POM files are no longer uploaded.
AAR files still are correctly uploaded but without POM, the library can't be used.

Here is a part of the build.gradle file :

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {

        snapshotRepository(url: nexus_mavenSnapshot) {
            authentication(userName: nexus_username
                    , password: nexus_password)
        }

        addFilter('legacyRelease') { artifact, file ->
            artifact.attributes.classifier.equals("legacyRelease")
        }
        addFilter('nbRelease') { artifact, file ->
            artifact.attributes.classifier.equals("nbRelease")
        }

        pom('nbRelease').artifactId = project.archivesBaseName + "-nb";
        pom('legacyRelease').artifactId = project.archivesBaseName + "-legacy";
    }
}
```

The only article that I found pertinent was :
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-upload-multiple-flavors-artifacts-with-different-pom-files-using-mavendeployer/5887

Their answer is to manually upload POM which I don't want to :)

Any advice ?

**Edit :**
While trying to get the POM back, I removed, flavors and still no POM. What I needed to remove was, hope it will help someone :

```
publishNonDefault true
```

Comment: Hey, were you able to find a solution?